# what is the wnck-applet?

Tags: applet

I just want to know what the wnck-applet is, and or what it does.
I located the program at /usr/lib/mate-panel/wnck-applet
`man wnck`
nothing. googled it, I see folks having problems with it, but nothing saying what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding [`wnck-applet` in MATE](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-panel/blob/c408d3eaf12ca962deb079d38980326cd2cb12a9/applets/wncklet/Makefile.am#L61) is legacy of GNOME Panel, before GNOME Shell introducion.

Some clues from [Debian codesearch](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=wnck-applet&literal=1&perpkg=1):

- [libwnck3/40.0-2/HACKING](https://sources.debian.org/src/libwnck3/40.0-2/HACKING/?hl=30#L30):

  > ```
  > gnome-panel/applets/wncklet/
  >   The actual panel applets based on libwnck (the window list, window
  >   selector, workspace switcher and show desktop button) are found in
  >   this directory under gnome-panel, and all run as the process
  >  "wnck-applet".
  > ```
- [org.mate.panel.Wncklet.mate-panel-applet.desktop.in.in](https://sources.debian.org/src/mate-panel/1.24.1-1/applets/wncklet/org.mate.panel.Wncklet.mate-panel-applet.desktop.in.in/?hl=45#L8)

  > ```
  > ...
  > [WindowMenuApplet]
  > Name=Window Selector
  > Description=Switch between open windows using a menu
  > ...
  > MateComponentId=OAFIID:MATE_WindowMenuApplet;
  > ...
  > X-MATE-Bugzilla-OtherBinaries=wnck-applet
  >
  > [WorkspaceSwitcherApplet]
  > Name=Workspace Switcher
  > Description=Switch between workspaces
  > ...
  > MateComponentId=OAFIID:MATE_WorkspaceSwitcherApplet;OAFIID:MATE_PagerApplet;
  > X-MATE-Bugzilla-OtherBinaries=wnck-applet
  >
  > [WindowListApplet]
  > Name=Window List
  > Description=Switch between open windows using buttons
  > ...
  > MateComponentId=OAFIID:MATE_TasklistApplet;OAFIID:MATE_WindowListApplet;
  > ...
  > X-MATE-Bugzilla-OtherBinaries=wnck-applet
  >
  > [ShowDesktopApplet]
  > Name=Show Desktop
  > Description=Hide application windows and show the desktop
  > ...
  > MateComponentId=OAFIID:MATE_ShowDesktopApplet;
  > ...
  > X-MATE-Bugzilla-OtherBinaries=wnck-applet
  > ```

In Ubuntu [`mate-panel` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/mate-panel) depends on [`libwnck-3-0` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libwnck-3-0), so above assumptions are actual.

As an experiment you can try to run `killall wnck-applet` on the system with MATE desktop using default settings. It will lead to crashes of the above mentioned applets on the bottom MATE Panel - *Show Desktop*, *Window List* and *Workspace Switcher* (and *Window Selector* if you have enabled it). Clicking Reload in each Error window will reload `wnck-applet` and all the functionality will be restored.